# Selecting foreign keys in Django REST Framework's Browsable API

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a simple `ForeignKey` relationship between two models:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="created_ticket")

class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I have a serialiser for each, with the user serialized within the ticket as a nested serialiser. What I would ideally like is

- in an update view of `Ticket`s on the Browsable API, being able to choose from a dropdown list of extant users, and
- when entering a username and an e-mail, the application should check if users exist with those parameters, and if so, assign them to the ticket, and if not, raise a validation error (the validation part I got working, the rest... not so much).

So far, I've tried to follow overriding the update/create methods, but when I enter a code, the application always tries to create a new object, then complains that an object with the same username (the pkey) already exists. I have tried getting some sense out of the documentation on the subject, but with not much luck.

***EDIT***: My update method is

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    usr_data = validated_data.pop('created_by')
    instance.created_by_id = usr_data.id
    return instance
```

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far with regards to overriding the update method? You are on the right track

Comment: First of all, I'm not entirely sure whether it's the Ticket or the User class that I should override the methods on, which is an odd start :) My proposed override is:

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        usr_data = validated_data.pop('created_by')
        instance.created_by_id = usr_data.id
        return instance

Comment: Sorry @souldeux - got mangled. I've updated my main post with a properly formatted update method.

Comment: No problem, thanks. I should have asked this too: can you post your serializers as well? And to make sure I am understanding: you want your Ticket serializer to allow you to choose from a dropdown of extant users. When you say "when entering a username and e-mail" where is that happening? Are you wanting the option within the Ticket serializer to also update the associated User model?